# How can I determine the storing standards, such as UTF-8, for files?

Tags: utf-8, standards, iso

*The question arises from the [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252998/how-can-i-compile-latex-in-utf8/1253024#1253024).*

How can I change the storing from an ISO-standard to UTF-8?

**Some details:**

I used Mac with some ISO-standard. I formatted it, so I cannot know the exact ISO-standard. Now, I use Ubuntu, and I try to switch my Mac-latex-files from the ISO to UTF-8.

Comment: you should put all the relevant information in this question; but only if you want an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: The `file` command may be able to guess the encoding of a given file.

To answer the question in the body: Try `iconv`.

Comment: Some Latex files are of the type "Latex files", while other files are "graphviz graph text".

Comment: Ok, if `file` can't (or won't) guess then you will have to know what encoding you used to create the files. Use `iconv` to convert the files to your desired UTF-8 encoding.