# Assigning const unsigned char* to a std::string performing in-place substitution or omission

Tags: c++

I have a `const unsigned char* bar` which is null-terminated character buffer.

I need to copy this to a `std::string`. Currently I use

```
std::string foo;
foo.assign(bar);
```

But for various reasons (due to `bar`), the odd character with value > 127 appears in the list. Replacing such characters with 32 (space) would be sufficient, omitting them altogether is preferable.

Is there a way I can do that replacement

1. After I've copied to the string. Use something like `std::replace(foo.begin(), foo.end(), /*something funky*/`)
2. Use some kind of predicated "back inserter" when I do the `assign`.

I'd prefer something on the lines of (2). Before I delve into a `for` loop, is there a more stl-like way I could do this?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to understand how the text is encoded

Comment: It's UTF-8 but I need it transformed to UTF-7 for LaTeX. The odd accented character (possibly 1 in 10000) comes back: I'm happy to scrap the outlying characters.

Comment: Use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and send the UTF-8 on to LaTeX  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252998/how-can-i-compile-latex-in-utf8

Comment: Or use xelatex, which accepts UTF-8 out of the box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick if you just want to omit values >= 128 (or `< 0` if char is signed):

```
std::copy_if(bar, bar + <length of string>,
    std::back_inserter(foo),
    [](char c) { return c < 128 && c >= 0;});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd prefer something on the lines of (2). Before I delve into a for loop, is there a more stl-like way I could do this?

Consider std::transform and treat both streams (the raw and string one) as a sequence of iterators:

```
const unsigned char* bar = some_data();
auto length = std::strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(bar));
const auto bar_end = bar + length;
std::string foo{ length, ' ' }; // avoid reallocations in transform
std::transform(bar, bar_end, foo.begin(), [](const unsigned char c) -> const char {
    return c > 127 ? ' ' : reinterpret_cast<const char>(c);
});
```